# столкнулся с проблемой с таймером (на java). он выполняется не бесконечно, а лишь пока условие в котором самый обычный код не станет истинным

Tags: java, таймер, minecraft

пишу плагин для майнкрафта который будет телепортировать игроков по окончании таймера (когда Deathswap.globalTimeLeft станет < 1), после этого Deathswap.globalTimeLeft опять должен становится равным Deathswap.timeBetween (20) и уменьшатся раз в секунду, после чего все повторяется. но на деле все не так, и после того как условие Deathswap.globalTimeLeft < 1 срабатывает код класса TimerTask просто не выполняется и еще одного обратного отсчета не происходит, хотя я тестил ту же программу но только с выводом в консоль (System.out.println вместо broadcastMessage) и все работало

Deathswap — мой основной класс в котором прописаны переменные и выполняется при запуске

```
    public static ArrayList<Player> playerList = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList<Player> playerInGameList = new ArrayList<>();


    public  static int timeBetween = 20;
    public static  int globalTimeLeft = timeBetween;
```

startGameExecutioner.java:

```
public class startGameExecutioner implements CommandExecutor {
    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender commandSender, Command command, String s, String[] strings) {
        int i;
        broadcastMessage("Game restarted!!!!");

        Deathswap.playerInGameList = Deathswap.playerList;
        
        broadcastMessage("");
        broadcastMessage("Players in game:");
        for (i = 0; i < Deathswap.playerInGameList.size(); i++) {
            broadcastMessage(Deathswap.playerInGameList.get(i).getName());
        }

        ScheduledExecutorService global = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

        global.scheduleAtFixedRate(new timerTask() {}, 1,1, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //ЭТА СТРОКА ПЕРЕСТАЕТ РАБОТАТЬ ПРИ УСЛОВИИ В TIMERTASK
        

        return true;
    }

}
```

timerTask.java:

```
public class timerTask implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Deathswap.globalTimeLeft--;

        broadcastMessage("Teleport in " + Deathswap.globalTimeLeft );


        if (Deathswap.globalTimeLeft < 1) { // ПОСЛЕ ВХОДА В ТЕЛО УСЛОВИЯ TIMERTASK НЕ ВЫПОЛНЯЕТСЯ ПОВТОРНО,

            broadcastMessage("TELEPORTING");
            Deathswap.globalTimeLeft = Deathswap.timeBetween; //ХОТЯ ЭТА СТРОКА ПРИСВАЕВАЕТ ПЕРЕМЕННОЙ ТАЙМЕРА ЗНАЧЕНИЕ 20


            int i;

            Player first = Deathswap.playerInGameList.get(0);
            Location bufLoc = new Location(first.getWorld(), first.getLocation().getX(), first.getLocation().getY(), first.getLocation().getZ());


            for (i = 0; i < Deathswap.playerInGameList.size(); i++) {

                if (Deathswap.playerInGameList.size() == 1) {
                    Deathswap.playerInGameList.get(i).teleport(bufLoc);
                } else

                if (i == Deathswap.playerInGameList.size() - 1) {
                    Deathswap.playerInGameList.get(i).teleport(bufLoc);

                } else {
                    Deathswap.playerInGameList.get(i).teleport(Deathswap.playerInGameList.get(i + 1).getLocation());

                }

            }


        } //    END OF TELEPORTING


    }
}
```

надо решить проблему без Thread.sleep(). писать на java начал позавчера так что буду очень признателен если дадите дополнительную информацию о таймерах

Comment: "писать на java начал позавчера" - не осень относится к теме вопроса. Но это меня удивило: прямо очень много за два дня изучили. И синтаксис языка, и ООП, и таймеры....